# Suggestions for Including Confidence Rating in a Citation

Tags: macros, citing

As I write, edit, and review my document, I'd like to flag how related a claim and the supporting citation are. For example, if a reference `Foo` speculates on a topic (and therefore I give it a low confidence), and reference `Bar` goes in depth and proves another topic (earning high), I would like the (draft) document to reflect this.

I'm seeking suggestions how to implement this both from the editing and display sides.

---

For editing, I could picture doing this in a custom cite command:

```
As shown by \cite{Foo:1942}{lo} and others \citep{Bar:1924}{hi}, blah blah.
```

Or outside with a custom command (again using {lo,mid,hi} or {1,2,...,10}):

```
As shown by \cite{Foo:1942}\conf{3} and others \citep{Bar:1924}\conf{10}, blah blah.
```

---

For rendering, it could be simple:

```
As shown by Foo (1942) {lo} and others [Bar, 1924]{hi}, blah blah.
```

But I could also picture a more involved macro such that things rated `hi`, `9`, or `10` do not display at all, and things are more noticeable as the rating decreases (using red or bold font for `1`, `2`, `3`, or `lo` confidence ratings). The rating could follow the citation (as shown above) if using a separate command, or if using a custom cite command, the rating could influence the display of the citation itself.

---

Any suggestions on existing packages, or implementation suggestions, would be much appreciated. I know enough LaTeX to create a simple `\conf{}` command that implements a basic version, and perhaps that is enough, but I thought I would seek community input on the idea and implementation.

Comment: Surely `\newcommand\conf[1]{\textbf{#1}}` and then a `\ifdraft{\let\conf\relax}{}` would be a basic solution?

Comment: @Seamus: Shouldn't it be something like `\ifdraft{}{\renewcommand\conf[1]{}}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the *interface* I would look for would be an optional key to the `\cite` suite of commands.  Something like `\cite[confidence=low]{Foo:1942}` or `\citep[confidence=10]{Bar:1924}`.  Then if it were omitted behavior would default to the unenhanced `\cite`.

For *implementation* try the [`xkeyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval) package.  There are others which do this kind of thing (also [`pgfkeys`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfkeys)), but this one is pretty good.  The wrinkle is that `\cite` already takes an optional argument, so care has to be taken to get that passed to the original command.

The biggest remaining question to me would be the *rendering* of these fuzzy references.  I don't think you want to change the font weight or color—that might just emphasize it.  What about decorating the reference with a certain number of tildes, with more tildes meaning lower confidence?  (Tildes are used in physics derivations to indicate vague identity.)

Comment: Agreed this interface seems ideal. As for rendering, emphasis could be good ("This claim needs a better citation"), or **de**emphasis could be used, so that claims with weak citations appear to have no citation. Simpler might be what you suggest: tildes or asterisks, etc.

Comment: After writing I realized this was something you wanted mainly for the draft copy, so if you do want to draw attention to fuzzy references go ahead.